# PostgreSQLでreal型のカラムを用いて検索をするには？

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL9.3.3をCentOSで利用しています。

```
CREATE TABLE latest_data (
    id bigserial primary key,
    observed_at timestamp,
    lat real,
    lon real,
    value real
);

CREATE INDEX latest_data_lat_lon_index ON latest_data(lat, lon);
```

というテーブルがあった時、

```
# SELECT * FROM latest_data OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1;
   id   |     observed_at     |  lat  |  lon   | value
--------+---------------------+-------+--------+--------
 178576 | 2014-12-21 01:21:00 | 76.15 | 148.35 | 0.0078
(1 row)
```

と、データは入っているのですが、以下のようなクエリを発行すると、値が返ってきません。

```
# SELECT * FROM latest_data WHERE lat = 76.15 AND lon = 148.35;
 id | observed_at | lat | lon | value
----+-------------+-----+-----+-------
(0 rows)
```

原因がわかれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

下記コマンドを動かせばわかるのですが、SQL文中の実数（0.15など）はデフォルトではnumeric型です。

```
# SELECT 0.15 IS OF(real) AS is_real, 0.15 IS OF(numeric) AS is_numeric;
 is_real | is_numeric
---------+------------
 f       | t
(1 row)
```

ですので、以下のようにテーブル中のデータをnumeric型にキャストするか、

```
# SELECT * FROM latest_data WHERE round(lat::numeric, 2) = 76.15 AND round(lon::numeric, 2) = 148.35;
   id   |     observed_at     |  lat  |  lon   | value
--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------
 178576 | 2014-12-22 00:27:00 | 76.15 | 148.35 | 0.001
(1 row)
```

以下のようにSELECT文中の実数をreal型にキャストして比較してください。

```
# SELECT * FROM latest_data WHERE lat = 76.15::real AND lon = 148.35::real;
   id   |     observed_at     |  lat  |  lon   | value
--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------
 178576 | 2014-12-22 00:27:00 | 76.15 | 148.35 | 0.001
(1 row)
```

ただし、テーブル中のカラムをnumericにキャストするとINDEXが効きません。

```
# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM latest_data WHERE round(lat::numeric, 2) = 76.15 AND round(lon::numeric, 2) = 148.35;
                                       QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on latest_data  (cost=0.00..54206.33 rows=39 width=28)
   Filter: ((round((lat)::numeric, 2) = 76.15) AND (round((lon)::numeric, 2) = 148.35))
(2 rows)
```

のようにseq scanになります。

なので、SQL中の数値をreal型にキャストするべきでしょう。

```
# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM latest_data WHERE lat = 76.15::real AND lon = 148.35::real;
                                                   QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using latest_data_lat_lon_index on latest_data  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=28)
   Index Cond: ((lat = 76.15::real) AND (lon = 148.35::real))
(2 rows)
```

となり、INDEXが使われていることがわかります。

参考：[Value of real type incorrectly compares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236784/value-of-real-type-incorrectly-compares)

Comment: (私の日本語は上手じゃない）たぶん、`76.15` まさにありません、ね？　計算からですから、Range (範囲？)のほうがいい　－　`WHERE lat >= 76.15 - .000001 AND lat <= 76.15 + .000001`。

Comment: lat:76.15というのがSELECTで取れている時、SELECT * FROM latest_data WHERE lat = 76.15::realが真にならない場合というのが存在するのでしょうか。ドキュメント（http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html）には"Comparing two floating-point values for equality might not always work as expected.（2つの浮動小数点値が等価であるのかどうかの比較は予想通りに行く時もあれば行かない時もあります。)"と書かれていますが、それがどのような場合なのかは言及がありませんでした。

Comment: err.. `1.0::real = 1.0::numeric` ほんとです。でも、`.1::real <> .1::numeric`;　これですから、(real) `.1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 <> 1.0`。`1.0` まさにありません。（近くに！`.99999999999....何か`）floating-point と　`=` わだめ、ください。